# Cross-Compiling xnu for 5s

Tags: c++, xcode, arm, cross-compiling, jailbreak

Whilst trying to build a cross toolchain I've come across this error trying to compile xnu for ios:

```
$ make SDKROOT=iphoneos TARGET_CONFIGS=armv7a xcrun: error: unable to find utility "embedded_device_map", not a developer tool or in PATH     xcrun: error: unable to find utility "embedded_device_map", not a developer tool or in PATH /usr/local/src/xnu/makedefs/MakeInc.kernel:14: *** Unsupported CURRENT_ARCH_CONFIG .  Stop. make[1]: *** [build_setup_bootstrap_ARMV7A^^] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I cannot find any information on this tool at all, let alone methods to install it or cross compile it for cortex-a9 (Apple a5)

Thus, I'd be ever so grateful if anyone could provide even a hint of insight. Where on earth can I find this tool?

Comment: Whoops, compiling for iPad Mini (iPad2,5), not 5s

Comment: Does the source code support being built for iOS devices?

Comment: Isn't XNU the iOS _kernel_? You're not perchance with the FBI, are you?

Comment: Source code for ncurses, readline, and boost libraries. I think I'm in way over my head, seemed to be missing a header file from xnu and started backtracking.... Please help lol